# Android - Adaptive Bit rate streaming. (HLS) Quality of stream

Tags: java, android, streaming, media-player, http-live-streaming

I'm new to adaptive bit rate streaming. Basically I'm trying to write an app that shows information about the quality of the connection on an Android device.

Since HoneyComb(3.0), Android supports adaptive bit rate streaming through HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). It seams like support for helping developers verify the quality of this connection device side is very limited.

What I would like to know is some low level information about the stream. Such as: the number of segments, the segment duration, number of requests to change bit rate, the bit rate the media player sees (to facilitate the change), etc.

I've been able to get some information about stream quality from the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html),  [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html), [MediaMetaDataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html), [CamcorderProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html), [MediaFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html), [MediaExtractor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html) classes.  However, the stuff I'm looking for is even lower level. If possible I'd like to be able to actually see how the player is communicating with the server.

I just started looking at the MediaCodec class, however I can't figure out how to get the MediaCodec from a mediaplayer. Or Maybe I just don't know how to use this properly as I cannot find any good documentation and examples.

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the low level information on the Android that I'm looking for? Is the MediaCodec the way to go? If so, does anyone have any working examples of how I could get the currently used MediaCodec and extract the information I'm looking for out of it? (Or at least point me in the right direction)

Really appreciate any help on this one.

Cheers

Comment: You can use a local (even in process) http proxy which will allow you to access all that information. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: @vipw Thanks for your comment vipw. I will look into it. Do you have any links to resources(documentation, sample code or open source projects) that I could reference?

Comment: Hi Dave, I have a similar problem in my hand. Did you get the solution to this ??

Comment: local http server is the way to go here

Comment: @Dave are you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, I found some information, but moved onto a different project a while ago. FFMPEG is an option if you are able to use it, lots of low level information to get using that player. I'm not sure exactly what's available with the newer Mediaplayer2. But when that is more widely available, there may be something there too.